# unable to read an AVI file in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, video-capture, video-processing, avi

I am trying to open an AVI file using OpenCV, Here is the code line which i used to read the video file.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI(video_file_name);
```

But it returns a cvCapture ponter which points to an address of 0x00000000 (hence an invalid pointer)

Can this be a codec related issue? missing ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem must be with the ffmpeg codec. there must be a mismatch between the binaries that causes a variable called icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p to be null, and logical check on this variable terminates the function before trying to read the avi file